# Autowiring Spring MVC vs JERSEY Null Pointer Exception

Tags: jersey-2.0, spring-boot

I am trying to autowire a Neo4J Repo in a jersey controller in a WebApp following the new trend no XML configuration. Got it working for MVC Controller but not for the Jersey where a NPE is thrown. Simplified code is [here](https://github.com/pvlastaridis/SpringBootJerseyNeo4j). I don't think it 's something to do with Neo4J as even simpler beans I do not believe they will get Autowired in the Jersey Controller. It might be sth in the Jersey Configuration. In more detail below here are the controller classes and the Jersey Configuration.

**MVC Controller.**

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {


    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/person")
    public @ResponseBody
    Person mvccreate() {
        Person tom = new Person("Tom");
        personRepository.save(tom);
        return personRepository.findByName("Tom");
    }
}
```

**Jersey Controller.**

```
@Component
@Path("/person")
@XmlRootElement
public class JerseyApi {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository; 

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
           public Person jerseycreate() {
           Person tom2 = new Person("Tom2");
           personRepository.save(tom2);      // --> Null Pointer Exception
           return personRepository.findByName("Tom2");
           }
}
```

**Jersey Configuration in main.**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="org.efurn")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {


    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/api/*");
       registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyConfig.class.getName());
        return registration;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        FileUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("graph.db"));

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);        
        }                

}
```

**Jersey Configuration Class.**

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("org.efurn.rest.resources");
        property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
        property(ServerProperties.JSON_PROCESSING_FEATURE_DISABLE, false);
        property(ServerProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);
        property(ServerProperties.WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);
        register(LoggingFilter.class);
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a bug in Jersey [JERSEY-2175](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2175) that prevents it from finding Spring components through a package scan, so you might have to register your components manually to get it to work.  E.g.

```
public JerseyConfig() {
    // packages("org.efurn.rest.resources");
    ...
    register(JerseyApi.class);
}
```

Comment: Nope unfortunately, the problem is still there.